# R lm function Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.4 Mb

Tags: r, data.table, lm

I have a huge data frame. I grouped all my data based on two columns The problem that when I use `lm` function with `ddply` I get an error `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.4 Mb`
. However, when I use it for another functions as `mean` it works perfectly.
Could you suggest me something that fix this problem, perhaps another function instead of `ddply`?
I have used the maximum limit by the way

```
    memory.limit(size=4000)
```

Here is an example:

```
                 a<- seq(1, 1000, 1)
                 b<- seq(2,1001,2)
                 c<- c(rep(1,250), rep(2, 250), rep(3,250), rep(4,250))
                 d<- c(rep(5,250), rep(6, 250), rep(7,250), rep(8,250))
                 df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)

               dafr<-dlply( df, .(c,d ) , lm, formula= (a~b ))
```

What I have experienced converting data frame to `data.table` helps, but I do not know how to use `lm` in the `data.table` framework.

THanks for attention.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your final goal? Also, what is "huge" (how many groups, size of the groups)? Maybe you can set the parameters `model` and `qr` to `FALSE` in `lm`.

Comment: Basically I have two thousand firms with five years daily returns. And I want regress for each firm's daily returns for one year (approximately, 250 obs) on some market index. I want to get respective coefficient of regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the coefficients, you can try this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dafr <- df[, as.list(lm.fit(cbind(1, b), a)$coef), by=list(c, d)]
setnames(dafr, c("c", "d", "intercept", "slope"))
#   c d    intercept slope
#1: 1 5 1.869449e-13   0.5
#2: 2 6 5.176935e-13   0.5
#3: 3 7 5.000000e+02   0.5
#4: 4 8 5.000000e+02   0.5
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. Works. One question, however. Why do use `cbind` in `lm.fit`?

Comment: Study `help("lm.fit")`. The first argument is the design matrix and if you want an intercept it has to include a column of ones.